# php array_combine only if keys match

Tags: php, associative-array

I have

```
$map = array('id' => 'clmId', 'name' => 'clmName' => 'value' => 'clmValue',);
$value = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Foo', 'value' => 'Bar',);
```

and I want to get

```
$expected = array('clmId' => 1, 'clmName' => 'Foo', 'clmValue' => 'Bar');
```

of course I did `$expected = array_combine($map, $value)` and it works most of the time, but fails (to my surprise) for following

```
$map = array('id' => 'clmId', 'name' => 'clmName' => 'value' => 'clmValue',);
$value = array('name' => 'Foo', 'id' => 1, 'value' => 'Bar',);
$expected = array_combine($map, $value);
//you get
//$expected = array('clmId' => Foo, 'clmName' => 1, 'clmValue' => 'Bar');
```

clearly, `array_combine` is not meant for combining associative arrays. What can be done to achieve this ?
I am doing a primitive `foreach($map as $key => $mapValue) { ...` but I am guessing a smarter map/reduce or some cool array function should do it for me.
Return `array()`/`FALSE` in case `$value` has no corresponding key from `$map`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function combine_if_same_keys( $array_one, $array_two ) {
    $expected = false;

    ksort($array_one);
    ksort($array_two);

    $diff = array_diff_key($array_one, $array_two);
    if( empty($diff) && count($array_one) == count($array_two) ) {
        $expected = array_combine( $array_one, $array_two );
    }

    return $expected;
}
```

Returns false if the keys don't match and an array if they did match.

```
$map = array('id' => 'clmId', 'name' => 'clmName', 'value' => 'clmValue');
$value = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Foo', 'value' => 'Bar');
$value2 = array('ids' => 1, 'name' => 'Foo', 'value' => 'Bar');

var_dump( combine_if_same_keys( $map, $value ) );
var_dump( combine_if_same_keys( $map, $value2 ) );

Outputs:

array(3) { ["clmId"]=> int(1) ["clmName"]=> string(3) "Foo" ["clmValue"]=> string(3) "Bar" }
bool(false)
```

Edit: Benchmarking

Just read some comments on another answer which suggested that `ksort()` will cause a performance hit, so I did a bit of benchmarking Ran `ksort()` on 2 arrays with (albeit numeric keyed arrays) 10,000,000 keys each which only took 0.010757923126221 seconds on
Intel Q8200 @ 2.33ghz (4CPUs), 3072MB RAM, Windows 7 x64 .

Edit (by OP): Number of keys should match as well
`array_diff_key($a1, $a2)` returns empty array even if `count($a2) > count($a1)`, the `array_combine` returns FALSE while generating a warning.

One can suppress it by `@array_combine`, but I would rather put the count condition (along with the appropriate empty() test on the `array_key_diff` return) and then combine the array.

Comment: Accepted and upvoted. Interestingly I arrived at the same answer an hour ago, but had to leave office so couldn't post it here

Comment: I wouldn't worry about performance hit of `ksort()` right now. Many will classify it as micro-optimization. Moreover I am pretty sure that my application will not have more than 10 keys (50 at extreme maxima)

Comment: Indeed, I wasn't worried about the performance hit- I just thought I'd see what it might actually be having read the other answer.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include `count($a1) == count($a2)`, otherwise array_combine returns FALSE (which is correct but) along with a Warning. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no builtin way

```
function combine_assoc($map, $values) {
  $output = array();
  foreach($map as $key => $values) {
    if(!array_key_exists($key, $value)) return FALSE;
    $output[$value] = $values[$key];
  }
  return $output;
}
```

---

Of course, you could simply [sort your arrays by key](http://php.net/ksort) first, but this does not take care of missing key/value pairs and has a somewhat decreased performance:

```
ksort($map);
ksort($value);
$output = array_combine($map, $value);
```

---

Version without foreach loop, which does check for matching keys, but I do not recommend it, since it will not perform well …

```
function combine_assoc_slow($map, $value) {
  ksort($map);
  ksort($value);
  if(array_keys($map) != array_keys($value)) return FALSE;
  return array_combine($map, $value);
}
```

Comment: Your `combine_assoc` function looks fine, except that you use the variable name `$value` for 2 variables and will have a collision.

Answer (score 0):

So `array_combine` doesn't work if the order is different? Well, easiest solution for you: sorting both arrays by key!

```
$map = array('id' => 'clmId', 'name' => 'clmName' => 'value' => 'clmValue');
$value = array('name' => 'Foo', 'id' => 1, 'value' => 'Bar');

ksort($map);
ksort($value);

// keys are "aligned", ready to combine
$expected = array_combine($map, $value);
```

Comment: kickass ! I love SO because, most of the time, I have to actually wait to accept the answer, this is really quick and to the point. Thanks a lot.

Comment: sorry to report this, the ksort is nice and handy, but this solution doesn't return false if keys dont match :(